# Fork and Sheet Lightning

Tags: everyday-life, weather, lightning

I've noticed that during British lightning storms, I have only ever seen [sheet lightning](http://fireflyforest.net/images/firefly/2006/November/Arizona-sky-3.jpg)

[image: sheet lightning photo]

However, on holiday in other countries, I frequently see [Forked Lightning](http://openlettersmonthly.com/issue/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/fork-lightning.jpg)

[image: forked lightning photo]

**Q)** Is this just caused by cloud, or is it two distinct forms of lightning?

**Q)** Is there a reason Britain only seems to get the sheet kind?

Comment: Did you read [Wikipedia's take](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning) on lightning (which should answer your first question)? Also, have you more than your anecdotal evidence that Britain has a significantly higher proportion of diffuse cloud-cloud lightning?

Comment: I recently managed to get a couple dozen photos during a storm. This is the first time I used a DSLR and long exposure. In all the cases that I would have called sheet lightning I was able to tone down the highlights and to my surprise, at least one regular strike became visible. At least on that night, "sheet" lightning was simply the strikes with enough cloud to light a large area well enough to flood my eyes and give too little contrast to see the strike or fork. One had a great ball on one end (but mentioning "ball lightning" could invite no end of nonsense).

Comment: @ACuriousMind I should have tried Wikipedia before, sorry. I've only got anecdote. I probably see 2 or 3 lightning storms in UK a year, so that's probably >100 storms. I don't _think_ I can remember a forked one. I've seen perhaps 10 on holidays abroad, and I'm pretty sure most were forked.

Answer (score 2):

Sheet lightning is just lightning where you can't see the strike because there is cloud in the way - the phenomena is the same.

Lightning storms occur in Britain in regular rain storms, so along with lots of cloud which hide the strike. In places further inland the storms are associated with hot air rising over plains, so less clouds to hide the strike and so a more photogenic result.

Answer (score 0):

As a long time resident of the UK, I can confirm that forked lightning is not uncommon in the UK, so I think that the OP has just been unlucky.   Of course this is just anecdote.

Comment: :-) Perhaps you've been lucky!